# How do I get a reference from a JavaScript function to a class property of a JavaScript class that has been instantiated by another class?

Tags: javascript

My initial page load instantiates PageInit as follows.

```
<script>

    "use strict";

    let PageInit = null;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

        PageInit = new IPageInit();

    });

</script>
```

I had to `let PageInit=null` in order to put that reference into the global name space to make it visible.  I suspect that is wrong, because I can't imagine that every class that is instantiated has to be done so in global. (??)  So, guidance on the **right** way to do this is appreciated also.

PageInit(), once it is created has a constructor that calls a class method, which in turns creates an instance of another class:

```
class IPageInit {

    constructor() {
        this.InitialiseComponents();
    }

    //Class Method
    InitialiseComponents() {
         this.PageContent = new IPageContent();
    }
}
```

Coming from a C# background, I do not create an instance of a class with the class's exact name, as you see above.  The class name is "IPageContent", and the instantiated name is just "PageContent".  (Again, guidance on the right naming conventions is appreciated.)

PageContent(), when it is instantiated has a constructor that itself creates a property called "TrafficData".

```
class IPageContent {

    constructor() {
        this.TrafficData = "Paragraph 13.5";
    }

}
```

Later, in "loose javascript" code on the page, a function tries to make a reference to TrafficData.  I've tried two ways:

```
// page javascript

function LoadTrafficData {

    let x = PageContent.TrafficData;    // PageContent (itself) is undefined

    let x = PageInit.TrafficData;       // PageInit is valid object, but TrafficData is undefined

}
```

As you see, neither way works.  I do not know enough about scope and visibility in instantiated JavaScript classes to figure out what is wrong and what to do about it.  I am using plain vanilla JS - no frameworks, APIs, or Libraries.

**How do I get LoadTrafficData() (a loose function, not a class method) to get a reference to TrafficData?**

Comment: `PageContent` is a property of the `IPageInit` class. So you need to go through the `PageInit` global instance to access that property. Like so: `PageInit.PageContent.TrafficData`.

Comment: I replied to frodo2975 with the same suggestion.  I thought about the possibility of having to chain-reference the thing with double class references.  I will try that, though.  But it seems ugly.  frodo suggested "imports".  Would that get rid of the "weird" double class referencing thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that global variables are generally a bad practice. Modern js uses imports to import classes into other classes. For example, you might have a `PageService` singleton class that creates an instance of your `PageContent` class and holds it in a class property. Other classes could import your `PageService` singleton to use its properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Your naming conventions are a bit unusual for JS as well:

- Class names are normally capitalized, like `PageContent`, and instances are lowercase, like `pageContent`.
- Class methods and functions should start with lowercase letters.
- In typescript, you would prefix interfaces with an `I`, like `IPageInterface`, but you wouldn't normally prefix class names in regular javascript.

To debug your stuff, it's common to do `console.log(myVariable)` to inspect things. You can also insert a `debugger;` statement in your code to launch chrome's debugger at that line. To access your global var, you would do: `PageInit.PageContent.TrafficData`.

Comment: Ya know, that very thought crossed my mind (double class name chaining), but I've never seen it in Java or C#, so I was hesitant to try it.  But I will.  Thanks.  And thanks for the guidance, too.

Comment: `PageInit.PageContent.FlightData`did in fact do the trick!  But I don't like it.  Is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: Because, the way I am doing it, it is on me to simply **remember** the entire chain of instantiation and remember what made what and in what order.  This doesn't sound like sound doctrine.  lol.  I'd rather that when a class is instantiated, it simply be available by it's own name.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like nesting either. I usually do a separate singleton service for each type of data, as long as they're truly separate and can be cleanly separated. Also, you shouldn't have to remember anything. If you're using a good IDE, it should be giving you autocomplete for class properties and methods.